# No tests ran, when I start Pytest

Tags: python, pytest, assert

I have created a simple calculator in Python:

```
import numpy as np

def add(a, b):
    """adds a to b"""
    tot = a + b
    return tot;
tot = np.add(2,2);
print("the sum is:", tot)

def subtract(a, b):
    """subtracts a from b"""
    sot = a - b
    return sot;
sot = np.subtract(2,2)
print("the difference is", sot)

def multiply(a, b):
    """multiplies a and b"""
    mult = a * b
    return mult;
mult = np.multiply(3,2)
print("the multiplication is", mult)

def divide(a, b):
    """divides a by b"""
    div = a/b
    return div;
div = np.divide(6,2)
print("the division is", div)
```

I want to write a simple Pytest for the calculator ( I am new to testing with Python), but I keep getting the message "No tests ran". My test file is called test_calculate.py and the code is:

```
from calculator import calculate

def add():
    """tests calculate can add 2 and 2"""
    assert add(2,2) == 4

def subtract():
    """tests calculate can subtract 2 from 2"""
    assert subtract(2,2) == 0

def multiply():
    """tests calculate can multiply 3 and 2"""
    assert multiply(3,2) == 6

def divide():
    """tests calculate can devide 6 by 2"""
    assert divide(6,2) == 3
```

I am importing from the correct module, so I simply cannot understand where the problem. I am searching online for a solution, but can't seem to find a reasonable one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: to start with, your test functions need to be named with a `test_` prefix, i.e. `test_add(): ...`

Comment: Thank you! I modified the code a lot and now all of my four tests are passed